# Inherited methods not found in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance

I'm doing semantic analysis of java codes. Some classes are as below:

```
ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration -> TypeDeclaration -> BodyDeclaration -> Node
```

The Node class is like this:

```
public abstract class Node {

private final int beginLine;

private final int beginColumn;

private Scope enclosingScope;

@Deprecated
public Node(int line, int column) {
    this.beginLine = line;
    this.beginColumn = column;
    this.endLine = line;
    this.endColumn = column;
}

public Node(int beginLine, int beginColumn, int endLine, int endColumn) {
    this.beginLine = beginLine;
    this.beginColumn = beginColumn;
    this.endLine = endLine;
    this.endColumn = endColumn;
}

public void setMyScope(Scope enclosingScope) {
    this.enclosingScope = enclosingScope;
}

public Scope getMyScope() {
    return enclosingScope;
}

public final int getBeginLine() {
    return beginLine;
}

public final int getBeginColumn() {
    return beginColumn;
} ... ...
```

Now, when I call these methods from an instance of `ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration`, any method is available except the `setMyScope()` and `getMyScope()`. Kinda a newbie. No idea why and how to fix it.

Codes of ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration is as below:

```
public final class ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration extends TypeDeclaration {

private final List<AnnotationExpr> annotations;

private final boolean isInterface;

private final List<TypeParameter> typeParameters;

private final List<ClassOrInterfaceType> extendsList;

private final List<ClassOrInterfaceType> implementsList;

public ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration(int line, int column, JavadocComment javaDoc, int modifiers, List<AnnotationExpr> annotations, boolean isInterface, String name, List<TypeParameter> typeParameters, List<ClassOrInterfaceType> extendsList, List<ClassOrInterfaceType> implementsList, List<BodyDeclaration> members) {
    super(line, column, javaDoc, name, modifiers, members);
    this.annotations = annotations;
    this.isInterface = isInterface;
    this.typeParameters = typeParameters;
    this.extendsList = extendsList;
    this.implementsList = implementsList;
}

public List<AnnotationExpr> getAnnotations() {
    return annotations;
}

public boolean isInterface() {
    return isInterface;
}

public List<TypeParameter> getTypeParameters() {
    return typeParameters;
}

public List<ClassOrInterfaceType> getExtends() {
    return extendsList;
}

public List<ClassOrInterfaceType> getImplements() {
    return implementsList;
}

@Override
public <A> void accept(VoidVisitor<A> v, A arg) {
    v.visit(this, arg);
}

@Override
public <R, A> R accept(GenericVisitor<R, A> v, A arg) {
    return v.visit(this, arg);
}
}
```

TypeDeclaration and BodyDeclaration is similar. There is nothing about line, column or scope in them. However, while `beginLine()` and `beginColumn()` work well, the s`etMyScope(), getMyScope()` don't. The latter two methods were added by me. I suspect that I have done something silly but can't figure out.

Comment: what you mean by "any method is available except the setMyScope() and getMyScope()"?

Comment: When I declare "ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration n;" and type "n.", Eclipse shows all the methods I could use. There are getBeginLine() and other methods in Node class except getMyScope(), setMyScope().

Comment: It pops out an error: the method "setMyScope( )" is undefined for the type ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration.

Comment: Can you also put ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration code?

Comment: "The latter two methods were added by me." Did you recompile the code after adding those methods? Do you have "build automatically" turned on? Do you have a Jar file on the classpath holding another version of `Node` without those methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like an issue where you are not able to reference the latest class version.
Possible issues :

- code is not recompiled at all
- there may be compilation error in other classes in the same src. Fix those and compile again.
- You may have the jar file path in  your classpath where the jar is not getting replaced with the latest one.

Please check if all these boxes are ticked. If the issue still persists, let us know

Comment: Thank you. I restarted Eclipse and found that all my adjustment made in Node class was missing. It seems that the system went down for some reason. I definitely had saved the file.